# Specify custom colors available in FOS CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, symfony4

I'm using FOS CKEditor in a Symfony 4 project.
In my fos_ck_editor.yml config file, i configured an editor like this :

```
fos_ck_editor:
    input_sync: true

    default_config: newsletter_content
    configs:
        newsletter_content:
            title: false
            language: fr
            toolbar:
            - [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'TextColor' ]
            colorButton:
            colors: '#DE1F35'
```

I want to use the configuration variable config.colorButton_colors as described in ck editor documentation but i don't know how to do that in the yaml config file.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line under "config:"

```
colorButton_colors: "F49800,B9B9B9,75A75A"
```